# How to read HP's manual about ram modules?

Tags: configuration, hardware, memory, hp-proliant

On page 48 in [this](http://www.hp.com/support/DL385G7_UG_en) user guide, it is explained in which order memory modules should be installed for an HP DL385 server with AMD Opteron CPUs.

There are 12 banks per CPU, and I have 6 x 4GB + 2 x 2GB modules for each CPU.

How should the chart be read for this complex case?

**Update**

- The 2GB modules are RDIMM and dual rank.
- The 4GB modules are RDIMM and single rank.

Comment: Which CPU sockets are filled? Is the memory SR, DR or QR? Which ones are UDIMMs and which ones are RDIMMs?

Comment: @mailq : I have now updated the post with the ram module specs. Does that change the ram socket order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU 1

- 4 GB in A (1)
- 4 GB in B (7)
- 4 GB in C (4)
- 2 GB in D (10)
- 4 GB in E (3)
- 4 GB in F (9)
- 4 GB in G (6)
- 2 GB in H (12)

repeat with CPU 2

Comment: Sorry but I'd put the 2GB modules in G and H myself, actually I'd leave them out altogether but that's beside the point. @Sandra, always look at the quickspecs, they have really clear loadout instructions towards the bottom.

Comment: @Chopper3 G and H are not on the same memory channel. This is why I edited the answer. My first answer was equal to your comment.

Comment: I know, but that's the point, to balance them across channels, that's the most efficient way of doing it (sorry, I'm a HP tin geek :) )

Comment: Good to know where I can address my next HP questions... I keep my answer this way to not confuse with the comments.

Comment: @Chopper3 : In my case the modules are both SR and DR, see updated post. Does that impact performance?

Comment: Not really, it's the quad rank ones where things get interesting.